# I get an error on using props in styled componment

Tags: styled-components

```
const TextStyled = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.primary % 2 == 0 ? "#eee9da" : "#d1ccbc"};  
`;
```

[image]

[image]

Why is there an error in the arrow part in the arrow function using props?

The grammar in the official document of the staird component was different from mine.

Grammar using the `$primary` key, how to specify the type of props that will go into the styled component, I've tried but I can't.
My environment is not a type script environment, and the version of the stale component is "style-components": "^5.3.11".